# Maximum number of cells in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am building an App that keeps track of your training.
There is a home screen (uitableview) that features the dates of the days when you excersised. Now I only want to feature the last 20 trainings. So is there any way to put a maximum of items on an Array, or a maximum of cells in a TableView, the oldest trainings will be replaced by the newer ones.

Thanks in advance,

Ruben

Comment: I feel like that would just be dependent on the amount of free RAM on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one way to do this , if you sort the data by dates , then you can put a fix number on the datasource method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                         numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 20;
}
```

You haven't showed how you populate the data, if it comes from a database perhaps you can  do a `SELECT TOP 20 ...` or `LIMIT` depending on the type of Db.

then return that array count:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                         numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [array count];
}
```

Comment: the capacity has no effect on the count. if no object is in the array, count will be 0. if you add more objects than capacity, count will be that number. capacity is just a hint during creation how many objects you might want to insert, so that during allocation maybe a consistent piece of memory can be used.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I didnt know that, I removed this part . Thanks for correcting

Comment: but it is obvious: if you count would be equal to capacity it would lead to many dangerous situations if there aren't enough objects — basically you would recreate the dangers of creating wrong-size arrays in c.

Comment: So you are saying you can append more elements the the capacity specified? I find it misleading

Comment: yes. capacity is only useful during allocation. it has no effect on later usage.

Comment: (actually I never found it that useful to ever use it in 5 years)

Comment: The docs are clear: initial capacity. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDFCGG